# Unable to run kafka with self-signed certificates

Tags: ssl, apache-kafka, self-signed-certificate

I am setting up kafka that uses SASL_PLAIN and SSL auth. I set one up in a public vpc so that I could use certbot to generate certs, but for this one I am setting it in a private network that cannot be accessed by certbot (and I cannot allow it to be accessed either).

So I want to use self-signed certs to do this. I've tried this:

```
openssl req -new -newkey rsa:4096 \
    -days 3650 \
    -x509 \
    -subj "/CN=$(hostname)" \
    -keyout key.pem \
    -out cert.pem \
    -passout "pass:${PASSWORD}"

openssl pkcs12 -export -out certout -name kafka \
    -inkey "key.pem" \
    -in "cert.pem" \
    -password "pass:${PASSWORD}" \
    -passin "pass:${PASSWORD}"

keytool -importkeystore -noprompt \
    -srckeystore certout \
    -srcstoretype pkcs12 \
    -destkeystore /etc/ssl/cert.jks \
    -deststoretype pkcs12 \
    -srcstorepass "${PASSWORD}" \
    -deststorepass "${PASSWORD}"
```

And in `/etc/kafka/server.properties` I have:

```
ssl.keystore.location=/etc/ssl/cert.jks
ssl.truststore.location=/etc/ssl/certs/java/cacerts
```

Where cacerts comes from is the apt package `ca-certificates-java` (and I ran `update-ca-certificates -f` too)

And if I try `keytool -import -alias kafka -file certout -cacerts` it gives the error
`keytool error: java.io.IOException: Keystore was tampered with, or password was incorrect`

In the logs for kafka, I see every broker spewing this:

```
INFO [Controller id=2, targetBrokerId=3] Failed authentication with 3.kafka.my.dns/10.1.1.1 (SSL handshake failed) (org.apache.kafka.common.network.Selector)
```

(I have changed the URL and IP address in that log)

How can I run kafka with self-signed certs?